# How to split each of these values using "," and add to one array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
[
  "Fri Feb 23 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time), Fri Feb 24 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)",
  "Fri Feb 25 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time), Fri Feb 26 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)"
]
```

Comment: Like `yourArray.flatMap((value) => value.split(", "))`? Like [JavaScript: Divide array elements on space and add to same list](/q/66227983/4642212)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
  "Fri Feb 23 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time), Fri Feb 24 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)",
  "Fri Feb 25 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time), Fri Feb 26 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)"
];
const result = arr.flatMap(item => item.split(','));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flat all and add to new array.
Example below:

```js
var data = [
  "Fri Feb 23 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time), Fri Feb 24 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)",
  "Fri Feb 25 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time), Fri Feb 26 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)"
];
var dataSplited = data.flatMap((value) => value.split(", "));
console.log(dataSplited);
```